# Website responsive not working on mobile even with meta tag included

Tags: html, css, browser, sass, responsive-design

I have designed a single page website, the responsiveness of the website is working fine in my localhost but after i have uploaded it to the github and host it, the website is not responsive in mobile device.
Here is my github repo link https://github.com/spideyhere/portfolio.git

and my live website link is http://mohdwasim.com/

I have attached the screenshot of mobile preview in my browser, which is totally fine but the same is not responsive in the mobile.

Mobile Screenshot
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: your website does not contain `viewport` tag. **live website**

Comment: but on my github, i have already included viewport tag in my index file.

Comment: I am not quite sure what causing that problem but the `viewport` tag isn't available on your live website. You can see the same using developer tools.

Comment: Just to add another perspective, i also don't see the ```viewport```. What's odd too, is the dev tools shows your ```meta= keywords``` but your index doesn't

Comment: https://spideyhere.github.io/portfolio/
this link of github is working fine in mobile but the domain link which i used with this link isn't showing my meta tags

Comment: Clear your browser cache and try again, this should get your css and html to update.